# WPF - Bind a List Box on Selected Item of Combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I have 2 classes A & B:

```
class A
{
    public long ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<B> BList{get;set;}
}

class B
{
    public long ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have a meethod returning a List of A class - **aList**.

I have 1 ComboBox and 1 ListBox. ListBox is using CollectionViewSource for Grouping/Sorting etc...

I want to Bind aList of type List to combobox. **A.ID** would be the SelectedValuePath and **A.Name** would be the DisplayMemberPath.

And then on selecting an item of type A in the combo, I want to bind the **A.BList** to the Listbox...

ALL in XAML...No code behind please

Comment: Please put up some XAML code that you have tried.

Comment: Dont bind to a List, Bind to an ObservableCollection instead since OC supports INotifyPropertyChanged, and will give you fewer issues than List.

Answer (score 1):

simply bind the selecteditem of the combobox to the itemssource of your listbox.

Answer (score 1):

What blindmeis said:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedItem/>
```

Comment: Need help, What about binding to a collection property of SelectedItem ?